# Getting data from file stream in c

Tags: c, buffer, filestream

I am trying to retreive data out of a FILE pointer and into a string. What is the best way to determine the size of the string buffer?

```
char string[WHAT_SIZE?];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("info.dat", "r");

fgets(string, sizeof string, fp);
```

Do I set the buffer size to something I think is suitable for that particular file? Or is there a more efficient way to do this without using strings with non variable buffer sizes?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but fread is for binary files, and my file is a simple ASCII file with "|" delimiters.

Comment: You can use `fread()` on a text file.  It simply reads as many bytes as requested (size * nelements).

Comment: Paynter You should always use binary mode when dealing with files. "Text"-mode is an abomination which just causes more problems than solves them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, You just have to pick a size and go with it.  Base the choice on max expected line length or record length or something like that specific to the input type.   Just make sure to check return codes and handle the case when the line is longer than you expect.

There are a few tricks you could play to get an exact size, however I can't remember ever having to use these in practice:

1. Do a ftell, read char by char, counting until you get to a newline, then allocate enough memory, fseek to rewind, and read the whole line.
2. Do a fseek to the end of the file to find the size, then rewind and read the whole thing at once into a single buffer.

Comment: This seems to me like bad advice. Why "pick a size and go with it" when you can adapt to the actual contents of the file? I think it's best to do the adaptation ad hoc rather than backtracking as described here, so that (e.g.) you can take input that doesn't come from a seekable file.

Comment: It depends what you are doing.   Tons of practical working programs have a single fixed input buffer.  After the input is in the system, they can copy it to a right-sized allocated string, or even just parse it on the fly and overwrite it with the next line.   As long as you have a good strategy for those lines that dont fit, this is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: I suggest that having a good strategy for those lines that don't fit is likely to be considerably more difficult than arranging that lines do fit in every case that isn't pathological enough to justify outright failure. Yes, of course lots of practical working problems have a single fixed input buffer -- and lots of them are vulnerable to buffer overflows, or have arbitrary and unnecessary restrictions on what input they will accept, or both. (Tons of practical working programs are full of bugs, too, but that doesn't mean we should try to avoid them!)

Answer (score 2):

Easy and straightforward way is to use `fseek()` and `ftell()`. After retrieving the size of the file, allocate buffer for the data and read the file in with `fread()`.

This example is a very common way to retrieve the exact size of the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* excepts file stream which is already opened */
long get_filesize(FILE *fp)
{
    long filesize;

    if( fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) ) != 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* exit with errorcode if fseek() fails */

    filesize = ftell(fp);

    rewind(fp);

    return filesize;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    long filesize;
    unsigned char *buffer;

    fp = fopen("info.dat", "rb");

    filesize = get_filesize(fp);
    if(filesize < 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    buffer = malloc( filesize * sizeof(unsigned char) );
    if(buffer == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    /* checking the fread return value is not necessary but recommended */
    if((fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), filesize, fp)) != filesize)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    fclose(fp);

    /* ===== use the file here ===== */

    free(buffer); /* remember to free the memory */

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to dynamically allocate the buffer and then grow it (e.g., with realloc) as needed.  That would likely require writing a wrapper function for fgets that would check to see if it read the full line (the newline character is stored into the buffer).  It would also have to handle EOF conditions.

This probably goes without saying, but using C to read and parse text files with variable width data is quite a lot of work.  It may not make sense for your situation or even be possible, but if you can use something like Ruby, Python, Perl, Awk, etc. you can probably get the task done in a fraction of the time.  You can accomplish in a few lines of code with those tools what could take a hundred lines of C. They are a perfect fit for reading and parsing a delimited text file.  For example, the following chunk of ruby reads a text file line by line and splits it up by vertical bars:

```
File.open("myfile.txt") { |file|
   while ( line = file.gets )
       puts "line: #{line}"
       a = line.split( /\|/ )
       puts "array: #{a}"
   end
}
```

Just for fun, here is a possible implementation with a few TBDs to handle (error checking). The main issue (aside from the subtle bugs that I didn't see) would be to address the freeing of the buffer if you don't read completely to EOF.

```
int myReadLine   // return non-zero if line returned, 0 on eof (see tbd below)
(
   FILE *fp,     // (I) open file handle for reading
   char **buf,   // (IO) buffer allocated by this function.  It is freed by
                 // this function when EOF is hit.  TBD: Should write a myFreeLine
                 // (for encapsulation purposes) to free this buffer for cases where
                 // you quit calling
   int  *len     // (IO) current length of buffer pointed to by buf
)
{
   char *ret;
   char *pos;
   int  curlen;
   int  remaining;

   if ( *len == 0 )
      {
      assert( *buf == NULL );
      // pick a number out of the air.  Could be app-specific.  In debug
      // it may be nice to start very small to force reallocs to exercise all
      // code paths.
      *len = 2;
      // tbd: need error checking
      *buf = (char*)malloc( *len * sizeof( char ));
      }

   pos = *buf;
   remaining = *len;

   while ( 1 )
      {
      ret = fgets( pos, remaining, fp );
      if ( ret == NULL )
         {
         // tbd: should check if error occurred here.  For now assuming eof
         free( *buf );
         *buf = NULL;
         *len = 0;
         return 0;
         }

      // check to see if we got the entire line.
      curlen = strlen( *buf );
      if ( (*buf)[curlen - 1] == '\n' )  // tbd:  check for \r?
         {
         // apparently we got the whole line
         // remove the end of line (at least that's what I would want)
         (*buf)[curlen - 1] = '\0';
         return 1;
         }
      else
         {
         // failed to get entire line
         assert( curlen + 1 == *len );

         // grow the buffer (tbd: realloc is a pain ... need error checking)
         *len *= 2;  // doubling is often a good plan
         *buf = (char*)realloc( *buf, *len );

         // set the "amount left" variables correctly for next iteration
         remaining = *len - curlen;
         pos = *buf + curlen;
         }
      }  // while forever

   // don't expect to get here
   assert( 0 );

}
```

And here is a sample call:

```
void readfile(char *filepath)
{
   int len = 0;
   char *buf = NULL;


   FILE *fp=fopen(filepath,"rt");
   while ( myReadLine( fp, &buf, &len  ))
      printf( "'%s'\n", buf );
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually intending to read *lines* from the file (which is the usual reason for using `fgets` rather than, say, `fread`) then what you need is for the buffer to be long enough to hold a line. You often can't know that in advance, so allocate it dynamically with `malloc` (or `new` if you're using C++, though in that case you might do better to use C++'s I/O facilities) and enlarge it when you run across a line that's too long. Something like this:

```
size_t line_size = 256; /* reasonable initial default */
char * line_buffer = malloc(line_size);
line_buffer[line_size-2] = '\n'; /* yes, 2 */
/* You should check for malloc failure here */
while (whatever) {
  /* ... */
  fgets(line_buffer, line_size, fp); /* should check for failure and EOF here too */
  while (line_buffer[line_size-2] != '\n') {
    /* we filled the buffer, and the last character wasn't a newline */
    size_t new_line_size = 2*line_size;
    line_buffer = realloc(line_buffer, new_line_size); /* should check for failure here */
    line_buffer[new_line_size-2] = '\n';
    fgets(line_buffer+line_size-1, new_line_size-line_size+1, fp); /* should check for failure and EOF */
    line_size = new_line_size;
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

(Warning: completely untested code; may consist entirely of bugs and toxic waste. Certainly doesn't have all the testing for error conditions that real code should have.)

You would probably be well advised not to let the buffer grow without limit if some idiot feeds you a file with insanely long lines; give up at some point. You might well want to encapsulate the behaviour above into a function, especially if you have multiple bits of code doing the same thing. In that case, you might also want to encapsulate its state -- the buffer and its current size -- into a `struct` too. (Or, if you're using C++, a class, of which the buffer-expanding-reading thing would be a member function. But, again, if you're using C++ then you should probably use the facilities it already provides for this.)